# In Oracle SQL Developer the same action as for dragging table to a worksheet, but in table's context menu

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL Developer 18.3.0.277 has a wonderful capability to generate diverse DML statements by dragging table name from Connections area to a worksheet.

This is not always convenient as I should be really quick and precise in mouse movements in order not to trigger some other action by accident.

I would like to have exactly the same functionality, but triggered by a context menu item. Is this possible? "Export" and "Quick DDL" context menu items are doing not the things I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't see that feature available outside of the drag-and-drop.

> This is not always convenient as I should be really quick and precise
> in mouse movements in order not to trigger some other action by
> accident.

If you mean the selection of an object and drag and drop is 'tricky' because we are by default opening objects on a click, make sure you have this disabled, and you might find drag-and-drop more palatable.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and I am the product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Drag-and-drop became really more convenient. But I still keep the context menu option in my "nice to have" list.